# Fixing IP Canonicalization errors

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, ip, canonicalization

I am trying to fix my IP Canonicalization error, but I guess i am doing something wrong.

```
 My IP is suppose 123.45.678.101
```

What I am trying, however I am having no luck. Can anyone give me a hand with my code?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^123\.45\.678\.101
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Website is using shared hosting then it will going to work. And if I am right then dont worry , it will also not going to create any problem bro....